# Combine Show and Edit actions in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I was just wondering if anybody has ever built a Rails application without any *Show* actions.

In my application, if a user picks, say a Project, from the list he will *probably* want to not just *show* it but also *edit* it.

So is it good practice to **not** implement any show actions and instead link all records to edit forms?

The only caveat I see is that a user might accidentally edit a project. But this could be prevented by setting a default attribute *disabled* on all form fields using jQuery. That way, a user will have to click a button "Edit" in order to unlock the form fields for editing.

Does that make sense or am I completely nuts?

Who knows, maybe this causes conflicts with Rails' RESTful architecture?

Comment: Why you don't you checkout inline editing. There is a RailsCasts on this thing explaining an awesome gem for the same. Here is the URL http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing?view=asciicast

Comment: I agree with you. Most of times, I don´t see the need of 'show' action. I'm making a small project, and after select the registry from the list, it goes directly to edit view.

Answer (score 1):

First thought:

In my opinion this could confuse your users because:
The usual url for a show action looks like this:

> products/:id

but the edit looks like:

> products/:id/edit

So if one of your users wants just to take a look (by clicking show) into a project it might get confused by the displayed url. You could fix this by using named routes but in my opinion this will definitely
conflicts with REST.

Second thought:

Before implementing jQuery logic just for enabling an edit action on an object you should use the built in mechanisms with a show- and an edit page/method, because the maintainability and readability will stay easier and clean with using default behavior.

Please correct me if I am wrong :)

Comment: OK, built in mechanisms are good, I agree. But maintainability suffers as well because I need to display a record's attributes twice, once in the show view, then again in the edit view. That's a lot of code duplication.

Comment: With duplication you are thinking about the line of code: @product = Product(params[:id])?

Comment: Why dont your open edit .As clicking on the product you are being redirected to edit the product and not viewing it. Its a wrong business logic too that you click on the show and opening form for the edit. Use right thing for right mean is right

Comment: @Flo: No, I was thinking about the show.html.rb and edit.html.rb files. They both contain essentially the same fields. The only difference is that in one file they are wrapped in p-tags, in the other they are form fields.

Comment: @TinTin81: I see :) Yes they contain 'almost' the same fields. But: If you have several models, which have different relationships, than it is great having two different views for different actions (logic). In a real easy model without any relationships it might be an interesting thought, but: Think a bit further: Writing tests will get harder, other people working on your code will need an explanation (time costs) and as I get to know it from my projects: sooner or later the App changes and every 'special behavior' thing can get really hard to refactor. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think having a `show` action is usually pointless if you're building a simple, namespaced CMS backend. Django-admin omits it, and a path like `/admin/blogs/post/241` goes directly to the edit form. I think this way makes sense, using the front-facing website as the `show` action.

It does go against Rails' default routing conventions, but not so much that you risk breaking something with an upgrade.

You can override the routes like so:

```
resources :posts, except: [:show] do
  get ':id' => 'posts#edit', on: :member
end
```

However, I would say just leave the routes as the `resources` method defines them by default, and throw the `except` option in there to avoid missing template errors if someone tries to go to `/posts/241`. Then you can just always link to the edit page.

EDIT: I will say that when building a CMS, I do like to use the `show` action, but not to just list the attributes. I like to use it as a sort of summary for that record, displaying some of the key information, when it was created/last updated, a list of its versions and who edited it (if you're into that sort of thing), as well as links to Edit, Destroy, or visit the record on the front-end website.

Comment: if it is `on: :member`, do you still need `:id`?

Answer (score 0):

What I would prefer is renaming edit.html.erb to  show.html.erb, and then have the edit action render show view at the end.

If edit.html is the only file in your web folder, you'd probably just rename it to index.html right? Rather than writing "Index edit.html" in a new .htaccess file just to make edit.html the default index file.

Alternatively if you prefer your view file be named "edit.html.erb" instead, you can just delete show.html.erb, and have the show action render the edit view (using "render :edit").

I would not recommend omitting the show action altogether, cuz that would make product/:id/edit the only reachable URL, while product/:id will return a 404.

It's up to you if you want your canonical URL be product/:id/edit or product/:id, but product/:id should at least render the same view or be redirected to product/:id/edit

Answer (score 0):

Single page webs are the way we are going, especially with Ember.js etc. Loading a new page to enable editing seems a bit old-fashioned these days. You can use the **best in place** gem to handle it.

There is also a Railscast on this topic:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/302-in-place-editing